# How to store a string and call it back later in the program visual basic?

Tags: ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

Hello guys I'm kinda new to programming so pardon my silly question. I have a code behind in ms access that stores the value of a variable. Is it possible for me to store that value in the variable and call it later. the problem is that the variable changes and i would like to be able to call the original value at some point.

```
Private Sub TabCtl9_Change()
    Dim store As String
    store = Me.Type
    If Me.TabCtl9 = 1 Then
       Call Files_Click 'the value of the variable will change here
    Else
       Me.Type.Visible = True
       Me.Type.Value = store 'return previous value here
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why don't you just go for it and try it out as you seem to have the code to support what you want to do?  Testing is very powerful: try something and see if works! Storing the value in a variable in the code behind module is a valid approach, as would creating a hidden control on the form.

Comment: I ran that code but it returned the previous changed value instead of the stored value. the code executes each time i click a different control tab causing me to loose the original value in the variable. I hope i'm making sense. i'm not able to post a picture to make myself clearer.

Comment: You can post an image here, I've used imagur.com for this purpose before.  Something that would be VERY useful for you to use is the debugging capabilities in the VBA Editor: breakpoints, Immediate Window, Watches.  Then you can step through your code line-by-line and see exactly when the variable is being reset.  If you run the code multiple times then the value of `store` will change each time.  Why does Files_Click change the value of the variable?  The variable `store` is a local variable, i.e. it only exists inside this `Sub` and dies at `End Sub`

Comment: You can create a Global Variable that will retain the value the entire time Access is open -- unless you change it. From your code we can't tell how often you will change versus when you want the old value.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion guys and now I know that I need a global variable for `store = me.Type` that i can call back at the end of the private sub if the selection is `Files_Click`. Is there any example how to accomplish this. I cant seem to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks Matt and Wayne. I was able to create a global variable that stored the value before the change and return it as needed. life savers